# Can't find variable: _objectSpread

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a react native app and running into the following error when I run `react-native` `run-ios`

> Can't find variable: _objectSpread.

Does anyone have any tips?

I think it might be my react-native version but not sure.

Here are my dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "query-string": "^6.8.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
  },
```

Comment: Sorry this is my first StackOverflow question. Not sure what's the best way to provide information. :(

Comment: What is the version of your `nodeJS`?

Comment: node version 10.15.1. Just when I thought I fixed it and it started working again I get the same error again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, please update your `package.json` to reflect these changes and it should work:

`"@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0"`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue today when created a new React Native app. Tried various option including switching between web and iOS simulator but error persisted.

I have node js 10.16.0 and nam 6.9.2. My project was set to use Yarn. I even tried using NPM based project, but no difference.

What actually solved issue for me was to upgrade expo-cli to 2.12.2 (sudo npm install -g expo-cli). Then I created a new project,  and that worked as before without any issue.

Perhaps you shall also try the same, i.e upgrade `expo-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same and i cant really find any information about it. I also tried to change the node version to v12.6.0, expo-cli and yarn version to latests version. I'm using react 0.59.10 but you can also try the 0.60+ versions.